# How to download file with embaded string in php

Tags: php, download

I am downloading file with simple code from my server which is like

```
<a download class="btn btn-warning" target="_blank" href="<?php echo base_url('attachments/' . $row->delivery . '') ?>">Download</a>
```

There is some security issue in this like if anyone write `sitename/attachments/filename` the file is automatically download. What I want is it will be like `sitename/attachments/filename/ciphertext(embadedtext)` so it will hard to break the code. what should I do to implement that in `php`.

Comment: user base64encode if you want a unreadable text

Comment: you got some advance?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your files out of the server DocumentRoot then use something like this:

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```